# Are angels Muslim? (Sunni View)

Tags: malaikah

I understand that angels are definitely believers in some sense. But is it right to say statements like "I'm in the same religion as the angels"? There are big differences between Muslim humans and angels, but are angels considered Muslims? This would help me understand what being a Muslim means in such a broad sense.

Answer (score 4):

Broad sense or narrow sense, a Muslim is a Muslim whether one is Human, Jinn or Angel. There's only few requirements:

1. Worship and obey Allah
2. Not to associate anything with Allah
3. To believe and follow Muhammad (PBUH) as the Messenger of Allah.

The Angels do whatever Allah ask them and they know about what's being happened in between the heaven and the earth.

They believe in Allah, Believe in the last prophet Muhammad (PBUH). As there is no reason to disbelieve the prophet.

***Therefore they fulfill the requirements of "Kalima" `La-ilaha-iLLaLLah- Muhammadur-Rasulullah (لا اله الا الله محمد رسول الله)`.***

**Thus it can  be concluded that they're Muslims.**

---

**Allah says:**

> “The seven heavens and the earth and all that is therein, glorify Him and there is not a thing but glorifies His Praise. But you understand not their glorification. Truly, He is Ever Forbearing, Oft-Forgiving”
>   [[al-Isra’ 17:44](http://quran.com/17/44)]

What this means is that every created being is in a state of submission to Allaah and worships Him in a manner appropriate to its situation.

**He also said:**

> “Have they not considered what things Allah has created? Their shadows incline to the right and to the left, prostrating to Allah , while they are humble. 
>   **And to Allaah prostrate all that is in the heavens and all that is in the earth, of the moving** (living) **creatures and the angels, and they are not proud** [i.e. they worship their Lord (Allaah) with humility]”
>   [[al-Nahl 16:48-49](http://quran.com/16/48)]

Comment: A Muslim is someone who has submitted himself to Allah. Prior nations who submitted to Allah followed their Prophets. Hence your point #3 needs to expanded to include other Prophets as well. The true followers of Adam, Noah, Abraham, Moses, Jesus and others are all considered as believers (Mu'min) and had submitted to the Will of God (Muslim)